# CSS conflict on slider border width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adjust the left-border spacing on the main slider on this http://stevanbarry.com/dan-morris-template/index.html I want the border to be 20px all around yet the left side seems to be an extra 10px wide.

The offending item seems to stem from line 881 of http://stevanbarry.com/dan-morris-template/css/bootstrap.css

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I've tried adjusting line 32 of http://stevanbarry.com/dan-morris-template/css/jquery.bxslider.css

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport
```

but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you distill the issue a bit and post more of the relevant code?

Comment: Please try: ul.bxslider { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

Comment: By adding the padding inline it seems to move the extra border width to the right.

Answer (score 0):

On a quick glance it looks like it's the default padding-behaiour on lists

Try adding a `padding:0` and `margin:0` to the `<ul>` style.